# ElementClickInterceptedException when trying to select option in dropdown menu

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some prices from the website for different mattress sizes but the problem is that the dropdown menu is not of select type, it consists of a div with ul list of different options so when I try to click on an option it gives me this error. What can I do ?

here's my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time
import re
import logging
import traceback
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import exc
import mysql.connector as mysql
import io
import re

url ='https://thesleepcompany.in/product/mattress/smart-ortho/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,15)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.dk-selected.attached.enabled').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
opt= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.dk-select-options').find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("class","dk-option attached enabled dk-option-selected")', opt[5])
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("aria-selected","true")', opt[5])
opt[5].click()
opt=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.dk-select-options').find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
print_prices() #ignore it
print_price() #ignore it
```

this is the full error message I am getting:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-94877ec06aa4> in <module>
      4 driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("class","dk-option attached enabled dk-option-selected")', opt[5])
      5 driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("aria-selected","true")', opt[5])
----> 6 opt[5].click()
      7 opt=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.dk-select-options').find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
      8 print_prices()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     78     def click(self):
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 
     82     def submit(self):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <li class="dk-option attached enabled dk-option-selected" data-value="72%e2%80%b3-x-66%e2%80%b3-x-5%e2%80%b3" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="dk1-72%e2%80%b3-x-66%e2%80%b3-x-5%e2%80%b3">...</li> is not clickable at point (832, 483). Other element would receive the click: <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='dk-selected attached enabled']").click()

listValues = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='dk-select-options']/li")
fifthElm = listValues[4]

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",fifthElm)
```

Comment: it works sometimes :/ like once the id was "dk1-combobox" but another time it threw the error so I checked and the id was changed to "dk2-combobox"

Comment: Okay. Updated the xpaths used in the code. See if that works.

Comment: Nope didn't work. I need to scrape prices for all available sizes. this works for a single element but when I try iterate through the list. it throws a StaleElementReferenceError.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use `Select` class since the drop down is not built using `Select` and `option` tag. Instead it is Ul and li tags :

Below code works for me :

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://thesleepcompany.in/product/mattress/smart-ortho/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dk-selected.attached.enabled"))).click()
mat_to_select = '84\" x 36\" x 6" (Single)'
print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dk-selected.attached.enabled+ul li")))
for mat_size in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dk-selected.attached.enabled+ul li"):
    if mat_size.text == mat_to_select:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(mat_size).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply but instead of specifying the size like you did, can I directly fetch the size list from the webpage and then iterate through it like I did in my code? will it work? In my code I also tried with Actions but it didnt work, it's way random like sometimes it may work and sometimes it won't

Comment: can I directly fetch the size list from the webpage and then iterate through  - see this line in my solution `print(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.dk-selected.attached.enabled+ul li")))` - this will print the size of options we have in the drop down. it's 29. It's not built up using option tags so we can not use Index here. Your test case should know which size to select prior of it's execution

Comment: It threw the same error as my code, a "ElementClickInterceptedError" or sometimes a '"StaleReferenceError". rhat's why I asked if you tried it. the problem isnt to scrape a single price. I need prices for all sizes. Is there anything I could do?